# Which one is better for NHibernate collection mapping?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, collections, mapping

there are the following types of collection mapping in NHibernate:

```
Set
List
Bag
Idbag
Map
Array
```

Which one is better in use and why?

Comment: I went to the supermarket today and there were like 30 types of cheese. Which one is better?

Comment: I like blue cheese! ;) Which one do you like?

Comment: Parmesan. But I wouldn't use it for a pizza, just like I wouldn't use a `Map` to represent an unsorted list of non-unique items.

Answer (score 8):

There are no good or bad collections.They are used for different purposes.

For example if you have unique elements you should use set.

You can start from [here](http://sdesmedt.wordpress.com/2006/09/04/nhibernate-part-4-mapping-techniques-for-aggregation-one-to-many-mapping/)

Comment: Not "can use" SHOULD use **Set**